Title: Why Does WhatsApp Use Both CBC and GCM Encryption?
"I noticed that WhatsApp uses both CBC (Cipher Block Chaining) and GCM (Galois/Counter Mode) encryption in different scenarios. For example, CBC is used for transmitting media and exchanging messages, while GCM is used in Message Add-ons in Community Announcement Groups and Invocation Message Responses. Can someone explain why WhatsApp would choose to use two different encryption modes in these specific cases? What advantages does each offer in these contexts?"

imho, changing is hard..

"I think it's due to compatibility. For example, if WhatsApp version 1 used CBC, and in version 2, they switched to GCM, a client using WhatsApp v1 wouldn't be able to communicate with a client using WhatsApp v2. By using different encryption modes in specific cases, WhatsApp ensures backward compatibility while gradually adopting newer encryption standards."

Are you quoting someone else?
